# Any two bivariate algebraically dependent polynomials are always in the same ring generated by some bivariate polynomial?

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

If $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are two algebraically dependent polynomials over some field $k$, is it true that there exists a bivariate polynomial $p(x,y)$ such that both $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are in the ring  $k[p(x,y)]$?

Answer (score 10):

Yes.  Let $k[T]$ denote the $k$-subalgebra of $k(x,y)$ generated by a subset $T$, and let $k(T)$ denote its field of quotients.  Luroth's Theorem says that every field $L$, $k \subset L \subset k(x,y)$, of transcendence degree one over $k$ is equal to $k(p)$ for some $p \in k(x,y)$.  A sharpening of E. Noether (char $k$ = 0) and A. Schinzel (arbritrary $k$) says that if $L$ contains a nonconstant polynomial, then some $p \in k[x,y]$ suffices (Theorem 4, page 10 in "Selected Topics on Polynomials" , by A. Schinzel).  The hypothesis that $f$ and $g$ are algebraically dependent implies that $k(f,g)$ has transcendence degree $\leq 1$ over $k$.  Thus $f,g \in k(p)$ for some $p \in k[x,y]$.  Unique factorization in $k[x,y]$ and $k[p]$ then implies that $f,g \in k[p]$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any constructive proof telling how to find such a polynomial?

Comment: I have two clarificatory questions: (1) Can you explain how Luroth gives the stated claim about $L$? (I am accustomed to thinking of Luroth's thm as telling us something about $L$ between $k$ and $k(x)$, not $k(x,y)$.) (2) Can you spell out the appeal to unique factorization in the last line?