# Generalizations of Lüroth theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, fields, transcendence

Let $k$ be an arbitrary field (I do not mind to take $k=\mathbb{C}$, if things are easier in this case).

A more general version of [Lüroth theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%BCroth%27s_theorem) says that a field $L$, $k \subset L \subset k(x,y)$, of transcendence degree one over $k$ is equal to $k(h)$ for some $h \in k(x,y)$. 
Moreover, Schinzel in "Selected Topics on Polynomials" (Theorem 4, page 10) showed that if $L$ contains a nonconstant polynomial, then $h \in k[x,y]$ suffices (see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190920/any-two-bivariate-algebraically-dependent-polynomials-are-always-in-the-same-rin/191058#191058)).

Let $k \subset L \subset k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, $n \geq 2$, $L$ is a field.

> If $L$ is of transcendence degree $m$ over $k$, $1 \leq m \leq n$,
>   is it true that $L=k(h_1,\ldots,h_m)$ for some $h_1,\ldots,h_m \in k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$?

I guess that the answer is negative, by what Georges Elencwajg has written in his answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108766/l%C3%BCroths-theorem): "The analogue of Lüroth is in general false for the rational function fields $k(x_1,...,x_n)  \; (n \gt 1)$ : its subfields are not all purely transcendental extensions of $k$."

However, perhaps when $m \in \{1,n\}$ the answer is positive? Am I right?

> In cases that have a positive answer (if there exist such cases, except the above mentioned one), when it suffices to take $h_1,\ldots,h_m \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$?

I hope that my questions are not trivial. Any comments are welcome!

**Edit:** After receiving a few helpful comments, I have asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540914/a-pure-algebraic-proof-for-any-unirational-surface-over-mathbbc-is-rationa) (asking for a pure algebraic proof for the special case $m=2$).

Comment: The answer is negative for $m\geq 3$ for all fields $k$ (and for $m\geq 2$ for many fields). The value of $n$ is irrelevant. This is completely classical by now, just google "Lüroth problem".

Comment: Both of your questions have a negative answer for every n at least 3, even over the complex numbers, because there are unirational varieties which are not rational.

Comment: @abx, thank you! Please can you elaborate your comment? For which fields $m=2$ has a positive answer? Any recommended references?

Comment: @Tippi, did you mean that for $k(x,y)$ and $m=2$, there is a positive answer?

Comment: Is it true that the case $m=1$ has a positive answer for all $k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, $n \geq 2$? (by a similar proof to the proof for $k(x,y)$?).

Comment: Yes, the result is true for $m=1$ and any $n$.

Comment: @ulrich, thank you; is the proof for $m=1$ and $n \geq 3$ similar to the proof for $m=1$ and $n=2$? What about $m=2$ (with any $n \geq 2$)? Can you (or someone else) please elaborate about the results mentioned in the above comments?

Comment: For $m=2$ the result is true for any algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero. I don't know an elementary proof of this: in algebraic geometry terminology it is equivalent to the statement that any unirational surface over $k$ (as above) is rational.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am curious to see a pure algebraic proof for this (perhaps I will ask for such a proof in a new question).