# Solutions to $w_x=CA_x$, $w_y=CA_y$ other than $w=f(A)$ and $C=f'(A)$?

Tags: polynomials, differential-equations, integration, jacobians, jacobian-conjecture

Let $R \in \{\mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3], \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]\}$,
and let $A=A(x,y) \in R[x,y]$ with $\deg(A) \geq 1$ (total degree).

I wish to prove or find a counterexample to the following claim:

> If there exist $w=w(x,y),C=C(x,y) \in R[x,y]$ such that
>   $w_x=CA_x$ and $w_y=CA_y$ (the subscripts denote partial derivatives),
>   then necessarily $w=f(A)$ and $C=f'(A)$, for some $f \in R[T]$.

I have asked the above question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993124/solutions-to-w-x-ca-x-w-y-ca-y-other-than-w-fa-and-c-fa), but have not received an answer; hopefully, my question is appropriate for MO.

Actually, **my 'original' question** is as follows:

> Suppose that $A,B,w \in R[x,y]$ satisfy two conditions: 
>   **(i)** $\operatorname{Jac}(A,B)=1$. 
>   **(ii)** $\operatorname{Jac}(A,w)=0$. 
>   Is it true that $w \in R[A]$?
>
> Perhaps, if there exists a counterexample to my original question, then it is easier to find a counterexample in the first Weyl algebra than in $R[x,y]$, where the Jacobian is replaced by the commutator? See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315113/a-variation-on-dixmiers-counterexample-concerning-centralizers-in-a-1?noredirect=1&lq=1).

---

> **New edit 2:** If I am not missing something, the following is a counterexample to my original question:
>   $R=\frac{\mathbb{C}[a,b,c]}{\langle a^2-1, bc \rangle}$,
>   $A=(\bar{a}+i\bar{b})x+\bar{b}y$, $B=\bar{b}x+(\bar{a}-i\bar{b})y$, $w=\bar{c}x$;
>   see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038812/concerning-frac-mathbbcx-y-z-langle-x2-1-yz-rangle) for more elaboration.
>   Please, what do you think?

---

Any hints and comments are welcome!

---

> **New edit:** A counterexample if $R$ is not a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra:
>   Adjusting [Warning 1.1.17](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=wKJqqd8t8KUC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), we obtain: Let $R:=\frac{\mathbb{Z}[t]}{(2t)}$, $R[x,y]$, $A=x-\bar{t}x^2$, $B=Y$, $w=x$. 
>   We have:
>
> **(i)** $\operatorname{Jac}(A,B)=1$. 
>   **(ii)** $\operatorname{Jac}(A,w)=(1-2\bar{t}x)0-01=10-01=0$.
>   **(iii)** $w=X \notin R[x-\bar{t}x^2]$ from considerations of degrees.

---

**Motivation:** The motivation to my questions is a [result](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1995-123-10/S0002-9939-1995-1257100-4/S0002-9939-1995-1257100-4.pdf) of Cheng-Mckay-Wang that showed that  the answer to my 'commutative' question is positive for $R=\mathbb{C}$,
and a [result](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.5202) by J.A. Guccione, J.J. Guccione, and C. Valqui that showed that 
the answer to my 'non-commutative' question is positive for $R=k$,
a field of characteristic zero.

Then it is possible to show (I can add a complete explanation, if one will ask me to)
that the answer to my question is still positive if we replace $R=\mathbb{C}$ by any field of characteristic zero.

Moreover, the answer to my question is still positive if we replace $R=\mathbb{C}$ by any normal integral domain of characteristic zero; this follows quite immediately from [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314251/f-g-in-mathbbzx-y-satisfying-operatornamejacf-g-0-and-f-g-noti?rq=1) answer (I can add a complete explanation, if one will ask me to). See also [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287610/if-f-g-in-dx-y-are-algebraically-dependent-over-d-then-f-g-in-dh-fo?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer.

Therefore, we are left with the case that $R$ is a non-normal integral domain of characteristic zero, for example: $R \in \{\mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3], \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]\}$.

We have: **(i)**  $A_xB_y-A_yB_x=1$ and **(ii)** $A_xw_y-A_yw_x=0$.
Then, $A_xw_y=A_yw_x$, so $\frac{w_y}{A_y}=\frac{w_x}{A_x}=:C$ for some $C \in R(x,y)$; hence, $w_x=CA_x$ and $w_y=CA_y$. 
Multiply **(i)** by $C$ and get that 
$R[x,y] \ni w_xB_y-w_yB_x=CA_xB_y-CA_yB_x=C$.

Next, as was calculated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993124/solutions-to-w-x-ca-x-w-y-ca-y-other-than-w-fa-and-c-fa) (my above mentioned MSE question), $C_yA_x=C_xA_y$, namely, $\operatorname{Jac}(A,C)=0$. 
Observe that $w_x=CA_x$ (or $w_y=CA_y$) implies that $\deg(w)=\deg(C)+\deg(A)$, so $\deg(C) < \deg(w)$. By induction on the degree of an element $e \in R[x,y]$ in the 'centralizer of $A$' (= $\operatorname{Jac}(A,e)=0$) we obtain that $C \in R[A]$.

Then, if I am not wrong, from $C \in R[A]$, $w_x=CA_x$ and $w_y=CA_y$,
it follows that $w \in R[A]$: Write $C=g(A)$ for some $g \in R[T]$, so $w_x=g(A)A_x=\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}f(A)$, where $f'(T)=g(T)$. Then, 
$w=f(A)+H(y)$. Then $CA_y=w_y=g(A)A_y+H'(y)=CA_y+H'(y)$, so $H'(y)=0$, namely, $H(y)=r \in R$, concluding that indeed $w=f(A)+r \in R[A]$.

The base case of the induction is $e=\lambda x+\mu y+\nu$; w.l.o.g $\mu=0$ so 
$e=\lambda x+\nu$. Then we have, $\operatorname{Jac}(A,e)=-A_y \lambda=0$, so $A \in R[x]$. It is easy to see that $A \in R[x]$ which has a Jacobian mate (= $\operatorname{Jac}(A,B)=1$) must be of degree one: $A=\delta x + \epsilon$,
and then indeed $e=\lambda x+\nu \in R[x]=R[A]$.

> It seems that the above arguments are valid for any integral domain $R$ of characteristic zero, normal or not; am I right?

Comment: For $P\in R[x]$ arbitrary, take $A(x,y)=x^2$, $w(x,y)=2x^2P(x)$, $C(x,y)=2P(x)+xP'(x)$.

Comment: Thank you! Truly, I meant that $A$ has a Jacobian mate ($x^2$ does not have a Jacobian mate). But it is my 'fault' that I have not mentioned this explicitly. (In some calculations I did in order to fotmulate this question, I have assumed that $A$ has a Jacobian mate).

Comment: By applying $\partial_y$ to $\omega_x = C A_x$ and $\partial_x$ to $\omega_y = C A_y$ we get $C_y A_x = C_x A_y$.  If $A_x,A_y$ have no common factor, this implies that $C_x = D A_y$ and $C_y = D A_x$ for some $D$, and then you can establish the claim by induction on degree. (At least when $R$ is a field of characteristic zero.  There could be divisibility obstructions in the integral domains you have.)

Comment: @TerryTao, thank you very much! (I have mentioned that $C_yA_x=C_xA_y$ in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993124/solutions-to-w-x-ca-x-w-y-ca-y-other-than-w-fa-and-c-fa, but did not know how exactly this may help). In my case, indeed $A_x$ and $A_y$ have no common factor (since there exists $B \in R[x,y]$ such that $A_xB_y-A_yB_x=1$). However, I wish that $R$ will be a non-normal integral domain, not a field; is there a counterexample in that case?

Comment: (I guess that it was meant that: $C_x=DA_x$ and $C_y=DA_y$). Now, perhaps it would be easier to find a counterexample to the non-commutative analogous question, in the first Weyl algebra; I will soon ask this in a separate question.