# A variation on Dixmier's counterexample concerning centralizers in $A_1$

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, weyl-algebra, centralisers

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210438/commuting-elements-in-weyl-algebras-of-characteristic-zero) question asks the following: "Suppose $k$ is a field of characteristic zero and $P$ and $Q$ are commuting elements of the first Weyl algebra. Is it true that $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials in some third element $H$?"

It was answered in the negative (the counterexample seems to be due to Dixmier and Makar-Limanov).

Now replace the field of characteristic zero $k$ by a non-normal integral domain of characteristic zero $R$, for example $R=\mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3]$.

> Is it possible to adjust $P$ and $Q$ to some $\tilde{P}$ and $\tilde{Q}$ satisfying the following three conditions:
>
> **(i)** $[\tilde{P},\tilde{Q}]=0$.
>
> **(ii)** $\tilde{P}$ and $\tilde{Q}$ are not polynomials in some third element $H$.
>
> **(iii)** $\tilde{P}$ has a 'Dixmier mate', namely, there exists $B$ in the first Weyl algebra over $R$ such that $[\tilde{P},B]=1$.

**Remarks:**

**(1)** The analogous question in $R[x,y]$ can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315073/solutions-to-w-x-ca-x-w-y-ca-y-other-than-w-fa-and-c-fa).

**(2)** In contrast, in $k[x,y]$, it is true that if $\operatorname{Jac}(p,q)=0$, then $p=u(h)$ and $q=v(h)$, for some $h \in k[x,y]$, $u(T),v(T) \in k[T]$; see, for example, [Corollary 1.3](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/39334102.pdf) in Nagata's paper ($k$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero) or [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190920/any-two-bivariate-algebraically-dependent-polynomials-are-always-in-the-same-rin) question ($k$ is an arbitrary field).
$k$ can be replaced by any normal integral domain of characteristic zero, see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314251/f-g-in-mathbbzx-y-satisfying-operatornamejacf-g-0-and-f-g-noti?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer.

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: If we allow $H$ to equal $\tilde{P}$ or $\tilde{Q}$, then the answer is negative, due to https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.5202. Indeed, apply Theorem 2.11 to (i)+(iii) and get that $\tilde{Q} \in k[\tilde{P}]$. Therefore, (ii) is not satisfied (just take $H=\tilde{P}$).